# What work-arounds can be applied to thread-unsafe autoload in ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, autoload, monkeypatching

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100701/why-cant-i-access-some-library-classes-when-im-in-a-thread), autoloading within a thread can cause problems. What work-arounds can be applied?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply require the files containing the classes you need, before spawning threads. It is a bit more work to get running than simply using autorequires, but it is necessary here.

That way you avoid having a class being loaded on multiple threads due to racing conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could roll your own with a `const_missing` plus a Mutex.